# Use PHP to run a shell script

Tags: php, shell, ssh

Now I know this question has been asked a few times, but I've followed everyone's suggestions and I'm still stumped.

I have a shell script (/var/www/scripts/test.sh):

```
ssh_con="ssh-user@x.x.x.x"
key="/home/user/.ssh/key"

echo "export start"
ssh -i $key $ssh_con "php /file/location/ service:batch:job export --env=prod"
echo "export complete"
```

the script has the following permissions:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data     www-data     1792 Jun  3 10:44 bash_script.sh*
```

the code im running in php is:

```
try { 
$outbuf=shell_exec("sh /var/www/scripts/test.sh");
echo "<pre>".$outbuf."</pre>";

}catch (Exception $e) { //while an error has occured
echo "==> Error: ".$e->getMessage();
exit();
}
```

When I view this from a web browser I get:

```
export start
export complete
```

However, `ssh` does not run.

I can  confirm that php.ini allows `exec` and `shell_exec`.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Have you try to run your shell script in terminal?

Comment: yes.. and it works without fail. @weigreen

Comment: Try `putenv("PATH", "/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin");` before you call `shell_exec();`.

Comment: Is that you complete shell script? No header line?

Comment: Which user is your php run at. Does it have permission to your shell script?

Comment: the shell script has a header line, I took that out of the question for simplicity @Tigger

Comment: @Will I tried this to no avail.

Comment: @weigreen this shell script is run by the webserver, which is www-data on this machine. it echo's so its running the script, but not the ssh part.

Comment: add option `t` to `ssh`    like following:  `ssh -i $key $ssh_con  -t "php /file/location/ service:batch:job export --env=prod"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your script is already executable, you should call it directly. Just put a shebang on top and you've removed one layer of complication.

Next, redirect standard error from `ssh` to standard output so that PHP can show you any error messages.

I'd be willing to bet that you'll find `ssh` is complaining about the key. You'll need to put that key file somewhere else. An SSH key in a user directory typically has 600 permissions.

Finally, `shell_exec()` won't throw anything you can catch. If you want to know if the process succeeded, you can use a different function. In that case it might be a good idea to pass on the exit status that matters.

So, to sum up:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh_con="ssh-user@x.x.x.x"
key="/home/user/.ssh/key"

echo "export start"
ssh -i "$key" "$ssh_con" "php /file/location/ service:batch:job export --env=prod" 2>&1
ssh_result=$?
echo "export complete"
exit ssh_result
```

And then:

```
<?php
exec("/var/www/scripts/test.sh", $outbuf, $result);
$outbuf = htmlspecialchars(implode("\n", $outbuf));
echo "Exited with code $result.";
echo "<pre>$outbuf</pre>";
```

Comment: I forgot about the permissions on the `key`, I think this could be the correct answer.

Comment: It was a permission issue with the $key.

Comment: @Mike good to hear, you should look at the other changes suggested as well, they will make your system much more robust.

Comment: I implemented all the changed you suggested. I also changed the permission of the scripts so they are only executable by the www-data group.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, the script isn't executing properly because environment variables that are present in your terminal session may not be when run via PHP. So calling `ssh` or `php` without them being present in `$PATH` will not work.

Try running this immediately before your call to `shell_exec()`:

```
putenv("PATH", "/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin");
```